# Can collaborative filtering be cast as a classical regression problem?

Tags: regression, recommender-system, unsupervised-learning

Having the Netflix challenge in mind: collaborative filtering is typically presented as a matrix dimension reduction.

My question is how does the problem relate to classical regression (supervised learning) problems? Can it be seen as an instance of these or does it differ in some fundamental way?

Comment: I am not an expert on them, but you might want to look at partial least squares http://www.utd.edu/~herve/Abdi-PLSR2007-pretty.pdf